# Table not getting created using sqoop import-all

Tags: hive, avro, sqoop

I am trying to create a different schema for AVRO based tables. Below is the command m using. I can see the proper directory structure with all the data files with .avro extension but when i log into HIVE & execute show tables; under retail_avro.db schema there are no tables

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--m 2 \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username=retail_dba \
--password=cloudera \
--warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db \
--create-hive-table \
--as-avrodatafile
```

After the above Command below is the Output if i access using hdfs commands:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db
Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera hive          0 2016-12-30 04:25 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/categories
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera hive          0 2016-12-30 04:25 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/customers
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera hive          0 2016-12-30 04:25 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/departments
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera hive          0 2016-12-30 04:25 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/order_items
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera hive          0 2016-12-30 04:26 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/orders
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera hive          0 2016-12-30 04:26 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/products
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/categories
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera hive          0 2016-12-30 04:25 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/categories/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera hive       1007 2016-12-30 04:25 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/categories/part-m-00000.avro
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera hive        959 2016-12-30 04:25 /user/hive/warehouse/retail_avro.db/categories/part-m-00001.avro
```

And When i login into HIVE :

```
 hive> use retail_avro;
    OK
    Time taken: 1.942 seconds
    hive> show tables;
    OK
    Time taken: 0.518 seconds
    hive> select * from departments;
    FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'departments'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sqoop Hive import is currently incompatible with `--as-avrodatafile` and `--as-sequencefile`. Please visit [Sqoop Hive Import Documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive) to get more information about it.
2. `avrodatafile` needs `.avsc` schema  and `avroSerde` to create a `avro` format table. Since you are generating `avro` file you also need the `avroschema`. Here Sqoop is incompatible with `avrodatafile` therefore `--create-hive-table` arguments is gettind ignored and therefore Sqoop is unable to create Hive table but it will import data into `.avro` format in desired directory as other arguments are correct and supported.

You can still generate a `.avsc` schema and create table on the same data. You can follow this [Sqoop avro import blog](http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2015/05/importing-data-from-sqoop-into-hive.html) to do so.

Please visit [Hive Avro SerDe documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe) to know more about avrofile format

Answer (score 0):

You have not created table in hive.

as "show tables;" have not returned any thing.

Please go throw section **7.2.10. Importing Data Into Hive** [link](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose)

NOTE: While importing or exporting data using sqoop you have to create table or table should present.

exporting to RDMS - table must present

exporting to HIVE -- Table can be created letter as it dump data on HDF.

Go throw https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe.

Comment: --create-hive-table args. This option says that if the table doesn't exists it will create it.

Comment: crate hive table from avro https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe..